# How to search for duplicate strings in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a data set from which I want to extract particular columns matched on the column `long_description`. In other words, two rows have different data except for `long_description` column, which should match exactly. How do I fetch the data with `long_description` column matched?

```
select `col1, col2` 
from table 
where `column2 count(column) 2 > 1
```

Comment: Join the table with itself on that column.

Comment: To find duplicate long_description values in SQL Developer:
`SELECT long_description, COUNT(*) FROM your_table GROUP BY long_description HAVING COUNT(*) > 1; `
Replace your_table with the actual table name.

Comment: Is there an `id` column (or similar) to distinguish the identity of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use a "self join" (join the table to itself) using that long_description field. When doing this it is vital to assign a "table alias" to each reference of that table (see `t1` and `t2` below), this allows for differentiating between the common columns names as shown in the select clause below (e.g. `t1.col1`). However you also will want some way to ensure that you are getting the dissimilar data in the other column so you may use additional condition in the join, examples below.

```
select
      t1.long_description
    , t1.col1 as t1col1
    , t1.col2 as t1col2
    , t2.col1 as t2col1
    , t2.col2 as t2col2
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.long_description = t2.long_description
                     and t1.col1 <> t2.col2
                     and t1.col2 <> t2.col2
```

another approach using `row_number()` may be useful:

```
with sample as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by long_description order by col1, col2) as rn
    from table
    )
select
      t1.col1 as t1col1
    , t1.col2 as t1col2
    , t2.col1 as t2col1
    , t2.col2 as t2col2
from sample t1
inner join sample t2 on t1.long_description = t2.long_description
                    and t1.rn <> t2.rn
```

this calculated row number ensures joining dissimilar rows.

A mock-up of these approaches is available here: https://dbfiddle.uk/XSn9Qnrf

As you will see from that mock-up the 2 approaches above are not identical (and are not intended to be) and you may need to fine-tune the join conditions to best meet your needs.